# PHP getting values from an array with even keys?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, key

Is there an easy way to loop through the values of an array using foreach but only targeting the even keys. For example an array like this:

```
[0] => val0
[1] => val1
[2] => val2
[3] => val3
[4] => val4
```

etc...

how could i loop through only even keys such as: 0, 2 and 4?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your foreach you can get the key too, just check whether thats even or not.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
  if($key%2 != 0) //The key is uneven, skip
    continue;
 //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: beautiful! should have thought of that haha :)

Answer (score 6):

this save 50% from looping

```
$even = range(0, count($arr), 2);
foreach ($even as $i)
{
  echo $arr[$i]; // etc
}
```

Comment: The foreach would have to loop less, but if its actually faster is another question. My guess is that there is another loop in the range function, thus it being slower. Anyway, its not even worth optimizing.

Comment: Please define another loop in the range function.

Comment: PHP's internal implementation of range most likely has another loop. But that would be faster, since its C++.

Comment: Moreover to 'range()' function, 'count()' function also internally looping to count no. of elements in array. Directly using for loop is definitely correct solution.

Answer (score 5):

I see that there are already 2 answers that would do the trick, but here's another one, not using `foreach()`:

```
for ($i = 0, $c = count($array); $i < $c; $i += 2)
```

Comment: Well, thanks. The `range()` solution is pretty neat too - didn't see that one coming. :)

Comment: By far the best and most efficient way of doing this, I use this often (still iterating but no pointless condition checks).. init $i to 1 to get odd indices.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getEven(array $data): array
{
    return array_filter($data, static function ($key) {
        return ($key % 2 === 0);
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=0; array_key_exists($i, $array); $i+=2) {
    echo $array[$i] . "\n";
}
```